# How to set Variable from parent class in child class laravel?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I Have Test class that extends TestCase, and i want to setup  `$base_route, $base_model` early, this is my Test class looks like,..

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class OperatorTest extends TestCase
{

     $this->setBaseRoute('master.operator');
     $this->setBaseModel('App\Models\Operator');
    
}
```

This is TestCase.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected $base_route = null;
    protected $base_model = null;

    protected function setBaseRoute($route)
    {
        $this->base_route = $route;
    }

    protected function setBaseModel($model)
    {
        $this->base_model = $model;
    }
}
```

but i got this error ? How to set Variable from parent class in child class laravel?

Comment: what error did you get.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)